# How can I count the number of occurrences of a certain object in a hash that matches a condition in Ansible?

Tags: ansible, jinja2

Given this list in an ansible variable:

```yaml
---
hosts:
- address: host1.local
  cluster:
    name: RED
- address: host2.local
  cluster:
    name: RED
- address: host3.local
  cluster:
    name: GREEN
- address: host4.local
  cluster:
    name: BLUE
```

I now want to count somehow the number of hosts in each cluster. So I want to end up with:

```
hosts_per_cluster:
   RED: 2
   BLUE: 1
   GREEN: 1
```

How would one go about this?

My first attempt was something like this:

```
- name: Get number of hosts per cluster
      set_fact: 
        hosts_per_cluster[item.cluster.name]={{ hosts_per_cluster[item.cluster.name] | default(0) | int +1 }}
      loop: "{{ hosts }}"
```

That did however not work...

Comment: Have you already tried the [`| groupby`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#groupby) filter and found it lacking?

Comment: Do not use reserved names in variables. The task should display `[WARNING]: Found variable using reserved name: hosts`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The task below creates the dictionary

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        hpc: "{{ hpc|default({})|combine({item.0: item.1|length}) }}"
      loop: "{{ _hosts|groupby('cluster.name') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  hpc:
    BLUE: 1
    GREEN: 1
    RED: 2
```