# Transforming ansible list into a dict of ocurrences

Tags: ansible

So, I have this Ansible data structure (variable):

```
variable:
  identifier_1:
    - 1
    - 2
    - 1
    - 1
  identifier_2:
    - 1
    - 2
    - 3
```

and I need to turn into a dictionary like:

```
variable:
  indentifier_1:
    - 1: 3
    - 2: 1
  identifier_2:
    - 1: 1
    - 2: 1
    - 3: 1
```

[How can I count the number of occurrences of a certain object in a hash that matches a condition in Ansible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66174507/how-can-i-count-the-number-of-occurrences-of-a-certain-object-in-a-hash-that-mat)

I've tried to apply the logic that is used in the above link but couldn't translate it to my use case since my list items are simply numbers.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use a custom filter:

you create a folder **filter_plugins** in your playbook folder (i have named the file **myfilters.py**  and the filter **CounterX**)

```
#!/usr/bin/python
class FilterModule(object):
    def filters(self):
        return {
            'CounterX': self.CounterX
        }

    def CounterX(self, obj):
        dicts={}   

        for k in obj.keys():
            mydict = dict((x,obj[k].count(x)) for x in set(obj[k]))
            dicts[k] = mydict

        return dicts
```

then you use it in your playbook:

```
- name: vartest
  hosts: localhost
  vars:
    variable:
      identifier_1:
        - 1
        - 2
        - 1
        - 1
      identifier_2:
        - 1
        - 2
        - 3
  tasks:
    - name: transform value
      set_fact:
        result: "{{ variable | CounterX }}"

    - name: display result
      debug:
        var: result
```

---

result:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "result": {
        "identifier_1": {
            "1": 3,
            "2": 1
        },
        "identifier_2": {
            "1": 1,
            "2": 1,
            "3": 1
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For example

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        f1: "{{ f1|d([]) + [{item: _len|int}] }}"
      loop: "{{ _unq }}"
      vars:
        _lst: "{{ identifier_1 }}"
        _unq: "{{ _lst|unique|sort }}"
        _len: "{{ _lst|select('eq', item)|length }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  f1:
  - 1: 3
  - 2: 1
```